# Memory Error, Pointer Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, linux, pointers

I'm writing a simple C program to take user input to create an arbitrary number of float arrays, and each array will contain an arbitrary number of floats. I have to use dynamically allocated storage and I'm having trouble creating the proper data structure. I've been reading about 2D array's and I to recreate that same functionality with using pointers.

Sample Run:

```
Enter number of Datasets: 
2
2
Enter size of dataset 0:
5
Size = 5
Array #: 0
Enter each float value:5
count: 0
size: 5
Enter each float value:4
count: 1
size: 5
Enter each float value:3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm not sure if my syntax for the array is correct, Im not sure how to get to the nth element of the ith array using pointers. Where as with 2D arrays I could simply put array[i][n].

I have a malloc() call for the outer array, and then one for each row. But how can I access and write to each element of the rows w/o using array[i][n] syntax?
I'm using the first element of each row to hold the size of that row.

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int numData;
int numVal;

float **array;




int main(){

/*get number of datasets */
numData = NumOfSet();
printf("%d\n",numData);
array = malloc(numData * sizeof(float));
if(array != 0){
/* get # of values per dataset and enter those values */
NumOfVal(numData);
}
else{
printf("Memory Allocation Failed");
}
}

int NumOfSet(){
    printf("Enter number of Datasets: \n");
    scanf("%d",&numData);
    return(numData);

}


/* for each data set declare size and input float values */
int NumOfVal(int data){
    int index; /* counters */
    int array_index;
    int copy;
    float size;
    float val;

    for(index = 0; index < data;index++){
        printf("Enter size of dataset %d:\n", index);
        scanf("%f", &size);
        copy = size;
        printf("Size = %d\n", copy);
        printf("Array #: %d\n", index);
        /* malloc() call here?? */
        *(array + index) =  &size;
        /* loop for entering float values */
        for(array_index = 0; array_index < copy; array_index++){
            printf("Enter each float value:");
            scanf("%f", &val);
            *(array[index] + array_index ) = val; 
            printf("count: %d\n",array_index);
            printf("size: %d\n",(int) size);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want `array` to point to a number of *floating point arrays*, which is consistent with your declaration of `float **array;`, then `array = malloc(numData * sizeof(float));` is incorrect. `array` is a pointer to floating point pointers. So this should be `malloc(numData * sizeof(float *));`. There may be other problems, but that's the first one I spotted glancing through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array` is a pointer to pointers of float. Thus you Need to allocated it accordingly for the first Dimension:

```
array = malloc(numData * sizeof(*float));
```

In the subsequent you need to allocate memory for each row:

```
array[index] = malloc(size * sizeof(float)); // or: *(array + index) = ...
```

Don't Forget to clean up memory! you Need to free first all Elements `aray[i]` and after that also the 1st Dimension `array`.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on how to write to each element in the 2nd dimension. So after
    array[index] = malloc(size * sizeof(float));

how can I write values into array[row][element]?

simply with array[row][position]?

Answer (score 0):

There are few bugs in given code, firstly

```
float **array;
```

`array` is type of double pointer, you should allocate memory dynamically for both `array` and `array[index]` as

```
 array = malloc(numData * sizeof(float*));
   /** allocating memory for each row **/
   for(int i = 0 ;i < numData ;i++) {
       array[i] = malloc(sizeof(float));
   }
```

secondly, the below statement

```
  *(array + index) =  &size;
```

should be

```
array[0][index] =size; // or something else like array[row][col] = size;
```

And finally free the dynamically allocated memory once wok is done by calling `free(array[index])` and `free(array)` respectively.

I hope it helps.

Comment: `array` is type *pointer-to-pointer-to-float* (which is commonly referred to as a *double-pointer*).